# Creating a dropdown filter for JSON data in Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use a dropdown that filters through my JSON data and displays different JSON data items if they match the dropdown option. So far I've managed to get it so a function runs when someone selects an item from the dropdown menu, but i'm unsure why the filter doesn't work, as i'm not getting any errors in the console or in WebStorm.

Here's an example of my code and JSON data:

```
<template>
    <b-container id="product-list">
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                <div>
                    <b-dropdown id="ddown4" text="Product Type" class="m-md-2">
                        <b-dropdown-item @click="FilterProducts" v-model="selectedCategory">4.5</b-dropdown-item>
                        <b-dropdown-item @click="FilterProducts" v-model="selectedCategory">10.5</b-dropdown-item>
                    </b-dropdown>
                </div>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <hr>
        <b-row>
            <b-col md="4" v-for="product in Products">
                <img class="img-fluid" :src="product.image"/>
                <h5>{{ product.product_name }}  </h5>
                <p class="original-price strikethrough">£{{ product.original_price }}</p>
                <p>£{{ product.final_price }}</p>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
<script>
    import Axios from "axios";

    export default {
        name: 'Products',
        data() {
            return {
                Products: null,
                selectedCategory: ''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            Axios.get('/products.json')
                .then(response => (this.Products = response.data.data))
        },
        methods: {
            FilterProducts() {
                var vm = this;
                var category = vm.selectedCategory;

                if(category === '') {
                    return vm.Products;
                } else {
                    return vm.Products.filter(function(product) {
                        return product.attributes.tog === category;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

JSON data example:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "83",
      "product_name": "TV",
      "category": "Clearance",
      "original_price": "139.0000",
      "final_price": "105.0000",
      "attributes": {
        "size": "260x220",
        "tog": "10.5 tog"
      }
      "url": "/tv"
    }
```

Comment: why do you have two                         `<b-dropdown-item @click="FilterProducts" v-model="selectedCategory">4.5</b-dropdown-item>
                        <b-dropdown-item @click="FilterProducts" v-model="selectedCategory">10.5</b-dropdown-item>` dropdown biding `selectedCategory` ?

Comment: Also do you want to show the filtered products? you might want to replace `            <b-col md="4" v-for="product in Products">` to              `<b-col md="4" v-for="product in FilterProducts()">`

Comment: Yes, I want to show the filtered products but even with that update it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your computed method is reactive to `selectedCategory` and no need to call `@click` as your are using `v-model`.

```
<template>
    <b-container id="product-list">
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                <div>
                    <b-dropdown id="ddown4" text="Product Type" class="m-md-2">
                        <b-dropdown-item v-model="selectedCategory">4.5</b-dropdown-item>
                    </b-dropdown>
                </div>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <hr>
        <b-row>
            <b-col md="4" v-for="product in filteredProducts">
                <img class="img-fluid" :src="product.image"/>
                <h5>{{ product.product_name }}  </h5>
                <p class="original-price strikethrough">£{{ product.original_price }}</p>
                <p>£{{ product.final_price }}</p>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
<script>
    import Axios from "axios";

    export default {
        name: 'Products',
        data() {
            return {
                Products: null,
                selectedCategory: ''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            Axios.get('/products.json')
                .then(response => (this.Products = response.data.data))
        },
        computed: {
            filteredProducts() {

                if(this.selectedCategory === '') {
                    return this.Products;
                } else {
                    const category = this.selectedCategory;
                    return this.Products
                               .filter((product) => product.attributes.tog === category)
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: that does run without error, but there is no change in the items that are displayed. they seem to all show, even if you select an option from the dropdown list.

Comment: UPDATE: This answer did work, I was using Bootstrap-vue.js and the dropdowns in this framework don't seem to work with this